# No puedo guardar la imagen con la ruta en la base de datos

Tags: php, html, css

no se muy bien donde estoy fallando. No puedo hacer que me suba la imagen, me muestra un error Undefined index: image, que he estado mirando en otras preguntas y no han encontrado solución. Tampoco se me pone en horizontal. 
I tampoco se denega lo de arrastrar la imagen, pero eso creo que lo puedo solucionarlo yo. Podeis editar el codigo para mostrarme errores o problemas.

Funciones de subir y mostrar:

```html
<?php
define('S', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
class DBImagen
{

 private $DBConexion;

 function __construct($Conexion)
 {
  $this->DBConexion = $Conexion;
 }

 /**********************************
 Función para guardar la ruta de la
    Imagen en la base de datos
 **********************************/
 /*Aqui definimos los tipos de imagenes permitidos y su peso*/
 public function uploadImage($Imagen)
 {
$types = array("image/jpg","image/png","image/gif","image/jpeg");
$limit = 4096 * 2048;

/*Aqui validamos si el archivo que se esta cargando coincide 
con los formatos especificados en el array $types*/

if (in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $types) and $_FILES['image']['size'] <= $limit) {

/*Con esta variable le asignamos un nombre nuevo a la imagen que se esta cargando*/

$imagename = date('dmyhis')."_".mb_strtoupper(substr(md5(sha1($_FILES['image']['name'])), 0,8))."_IMG.png";

/*Con la variable $path le asignamos la ruta de destino a la imagen*/    

$path   = "localhost". S ."aloysia". S ."SubirImagenruta". S ."imagenes". S .$imagename; 
$path_  = "localhost/aloysia/SubirImagenruta/imagenes/".$imagename; 

/*Aqui con esta función la copiamos en nuestro destino*/
copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path);

}
 }

 /**********************************
 Función visualizar las imagenes 
 que estan en la ruta guardada en la 
 BD
 **********************************/
 /*Aquí no sé si el $SQLStatment afecta de alguna manera cuando hago la función de subir la ruta*/
 public function viewImages()
 {
  $SQLStatement = $this->DBConexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productosima");
  $SQLStatement->execute();
 /*Aqui no se que pasa con este while, no me deja poner delante nada delante de él, 
 syntax error unexpected y lo que yo haya puesto*/
        while($img = $SQLStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
  ?>
  
  echo'<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>'; 
  

  <div class="row mx-auto p-3">
  
  <div class="imagen" style="background:url(http://localhost/aloysia/<?php echo $array['ruta'] ?>);"></div>

 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
  <div class="card">
   <img src="<?php print($img['imagen']); ?>"
     class="card-img-top" alt="Card image"/>
   <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
 
  <?php 
  }
 }

}

?>
```

Archivo de la conexión:

```html
<?php 
 /****************************************
 Conexion a Base de Datos con PDO

 *****************************************/
 try
  {
  $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=tienda','root','');
  $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }
 catch(PDOException $e)
  {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  }

 /*Crear el objeto para accesar a la clase*/
 include_once 'class.DBImagen.php';
 $DBImagen = new DBImagen($handler);
?>
```

Formulario:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <title>Subir Imagen</title>
</head>
<?php
 /*Incluyendo la conexion y enviando el Arreglo Files a la funcion*/
 include 'coneccion.php';
 if(isset($_POST['save']))
 {
  $DBImagen->uploadImage($_FILES);
 }
?>
<body style="padding-top:80px;">
 <div class="container col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#81BEF7;">
    <div class="panel-title">
     <center><h3>Guardar Imagen con PHP</h3></center>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="imagen"> 
     </div>
     <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
    <br>
    <table class="table">
     <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Imagen</th>
     </tr>
     <?php 
     /*Llamando a la función para visualizar las imagenes*/
     $DBImagen->viewImages();
     ?>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 <script src="lib/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias, tengo otras preguntas activas de esto pero que són del mismo tema, esto es para juntarlo todo y acabar ya con el problema que me esta dando tantos problemas, le doy las gracias a David Agreda por la ayuda, él me a proporcionado bastante codigo, estoy a vuestra disposición para qualquier pregunta.

Comment: Hola, te recomendaría separar los archivos **.php** y los **.html**, y para tener la funcionalidad de procesamiento de PHP, usa [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) sea en [JavaScript puro (XHR)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), o  en [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en el metodo `uploadImage($Imagen)`.

Tienes varias llamadas a $_FILES['image']['type']. Eso no es correcto. $_FILES no va a tener definido ningun valor dentro del metodo. Esto es debido al ambito de $_FILES.

Por otra parte, el indice `image` hace referencia al name del formulario. En tu caso el name del formulario tiene `imagen` y no `image`. Eso hay que cambiarlo.

Sin embargo, tienes esta llamada: `$DBImagen->uploadImage($_FILES);`

Esto significa que en tu `$Imagen` del metodo uploadImage tienes el array de files que le mandas en ese momento. Ahi si vas a tener los ficheros.

En tu caso, debes cambiar en tu metodo `uploadImage()` las referencias a $_FILES, y cambiarlas por `$Imagen`:

```
if (in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $types)
```

cambialo por:

```
if (in_array($Imagen['imagen']['type'], $types)
```

y asi con el resto de referencias de $_FILES que tienes dentro del metodo.

Comment: Vale, gracias voy a probarlo, pero lo de uploadImage($Imagen) esta bien? El problema es que el codigo para subir la ruta de la imagen me la proporciono un usuario de stackoverflow, y lo junté con mi codigo, entonces eso de uploadImage($Imagen) si no lo ponia me daba error, la pregunta es, cuando hago la llamada $DBImagen->uploadImage($_FILES); no hay problema con el codigo que te mencionado antes no? Gracias

Comment: para entender eso del codigo que digo, que el trozo debajo de uploadImage($Imagen). hasta el cierre, mirar esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/280146/131216

Comment: ambas cosas serian correctas, tanto `$DBImagen->uploadImage($_FILES);` como `uploadImage($Imagen)`

Comment: No me arregla el problema, sale el mismo error.

Comment: puedes indicar que linea es la que te dice el error?

Comment: Es Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\aloysia\SubirImagenruta\class.DBImagen.php on line 26 vale tampoco me visualiza la imagen ni me guarda la ruta, creo que es por el $SQLStatement que puedes ver en el codigo de la pregunta, eso creo que hay que cambiarlo pero no como. La linea 26 dice así: if (in_array($Imagen['image']['type'], $types) and $Imagen['image']['size'] <= $limit) {

Comment: ok. Añade delante de esa linea `print_r($Imagen); die();` y ejecutalo de nuevo. Si te da null o vacio, entonces la asignación de $Imagen no esta funcionando correctamente.

Comment: Array ( [imagen] => Array ( [name] => HADP Enterprise.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpDBFB.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 8455 ) ) Sale solo esto en la pantalla, (HADP Enterprise es una imagen que habia puesto de prueba, pero no se porque sale ya que al repetir el formulario no se guarda)

Comment: Vale. Nos acaba de decir que el contenido de `$Imagen`  tiene un primer indice llamado `imagen` y no `image`. Cambia entonces la linea del if, pero ahora el primer indice de $Imagen debe acabar con `n` :) Te lo edito en la respuesta.

Comment: ok, no te he contestado antes porque estaba probandolo, ha ver como va gracias

Comment: ya no me marca el error de undefined index, eso es un avance pero no me guarda ni la ruta, y tampoco se me muestra la imagen, gracias por la ayuda. Pueden editar codigo si lo desean. Creo que tiene algo que ver con el arreglo files,